# Characteristics, associations, or icons pertaining to Zoroastrian demons?

Tags: abrahamic-religions, persian

I'm working on an undergraduate term paper about the impact of the Achaemenid empire (so literature would have to be pretty old) on the development of Judeo-Christian demonology. I've found some lists of the major arch-demons in Zoroastrianism and their basic functions, but I would really like to know about some of their symbols and associations. Like for example, if any of them are associated with serpents or literally anything, such as a type of weapon it carries, etc. Any pointers to relevant texts would be great. Thank you!

Comment: In response to the question about actual zoroastrian demons or demonized zoroastrian gods: either would be useful but I was particularly thinking of the former

Comment: Ouch. I assumed we had the part of the Avesta that wasn't burnt by Alexander at the end of the Achaemenid period. The Sassanian one should be similar, no?